# CURL x-www-form-urlencoded request - PHP

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to write simple CURL request from server. Script looks like:

```
$ch = curl_init();  
$url = 'http://URL/';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
// ADD URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'Accept: application/json',
'Authorization: Basic Y291bn54adsASD78asd5LWFkbWlu'));
// ADD HEADER
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
// SAY IT'S POST
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response  = curl_exec($ch);    

if($response === false){
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else{
    $sessionID = json_decode($response, true);
    print_r($sessionID);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Problem is that I need to add some x-www-form-urlencoded like: grant_type = value, login = value2, password=value3. But I just can't make it work.

Can somebody help please?

Answer (score 1):

The values must be like they would be in an URL (hence the urlencoded), so:

```
grant_type=value&login=value2&password=value3
```

If values are not numbers, you will probably need to enclose them between quotes.

Comment: Hi Juan, I just edited URL on: 
$url = 'http://URL/?grant_type=value&login=value2&password=value3';

unfortunately, not working :(

Comment: As it's a POST, the parameters must be added in the body and not in the URL. I'm not sure how to do that in PHP, however. Please tell me if you find it so I can add it to the answer.